# Activate function at set position while running animation

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate, detection

I have been working on a music box kind of program but i have run into a problem.
My music box works with programmatically genarated created divisions that move over anouther division as a background. the animation is working and moving corectly but i want to be able to activate a funtion when the division is at a set location.

I Know i can do this by creating a loop which plays a small animation and checking every time the animation is completed but that is somthing i would like to avoid.

Thanks in advance

```
//this is used to move the div
$("#IdButtonMoveDown").click(function () {
      $('#IdDivToMove').animate({ "top": "+=100%" }, { duration: 1000 });
});

//i want to activate the funtion when the div has reached the 40% top
//position of the div that it is countaind within 
$('#IdDivToMove').???????(function () {
     alert("Set position has been reached")
});
```

Edit: i have looked at this for some time and while i have not been able to realy find a solusion. but for now i have just chained animations together like this:

```
<!--HTML begin-->
<div id="OutputDiv" class="OutputClass">
    <button name="TestButtonFalingDiv" id="TestButtonFalingDiv">Test create div Falling</button>
</div>
<!--HTml end-->


@section scripts {

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#TestButtonFalingDiv").click(function () {
            CreateFallingDiv();
        });

        //Set configuration
        //Maximum of 90 distance in totaal
        var intFadeInDistance = 10;
        var intMoveToMiddleDistance = 62;
        var intLargerDistance = 3;
        var intSmallerDistance = 3;
        var intMoveToEndDistance = 2;
        var intFadeOutDistance = 10;

        var intFadeInDuration = 1000;
        var intMoveToMiddleDuration = 6200;
        var intLargerDuration = 300;
        var intSmallerDuration = 300;
        var intMoveToEndDuration = 200;
        var intFadeOutDuration = 1000;

        var countingCreatedDivAmount = 0;

        function CreateFallingDiv()
        {
            countingCreatedDivAmount++;
            var SetID = "MovingDiv" + countingCreatedDivAmount;
            $("#OutputDiv").append("<div id='" + SetID + "' class='AnimatedDiv'></div>");


            $("#" + SetID).animate({ opacity: 1, top: "+=" + intFadeInDistance + "%" }, { duration: intFadeInDuration, easing: 'linear' })
            .animate({ "top": "+=" + intMoveToMiddleDistance + "%" }, { duration: intMoveToMiddleDuration, easing: 'linear' })
            .animate({ width: '8%', height: '8%', top: "+=" + intLargerDistance + "%" }, {
                duration: intLargerDuration, easing: 'linear',
                complete: function () {
                    alert("Function activation");
                }
            })
            .animate({ width: '4%', height: '4%', top: "+=" + intSmallerDistance + "%" }, { duration: intSmallerDuration, easing: 'linear' })
            .animate({ "top": "+=" + intMoveToEndDistance + "%" }, { duration: intMoveToEndDuration, easing: 'linear' })
            .animate({ opacity: 0, top: "+=" + intFadeOutDistance + "%" }, { duration: intFadeOutDuration, easing: 'linear' })
            .animate({ opacity: 0, top: "+=" + intFadeOutDistance + "%" }, {
                duration: intFadeOutDuration, easing: 'linear',
                complete: function () { $("#" + SetID).remove(); }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<style>
    .AnimatedDiv {
        top:                5%;
        left:               48%;
        width:              4%;
        height:             4%;
        position:           absolute;

        color:              white;
        opacity:            0;
        background-color:   blue;

        border-radius:      50%;
        behavior:           url(PIE.htc);
        display:            block;
    }

    .OutputClass {
        width:              100%;
        height:             100%;
        position:           relative;
        border:             red 5px solid;
    }
</style>

}
```

What this code does is when the button is clicked a div is created it starts the animation and at the end it deletes itself. that is a very simple explanation I know but this is essentially the only thing it does.

I am still looking for the right answer and if any of you know it please help but for now i hope this helps for anyone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `step` callback function that is fired at each step of the animation.It takes two arguments which is set to the DOM element being animated.Within `step` callback function you can compare the value of each step then if it meets your comparison, trigger your desired function.

Here is just an example to show you the approach  :   http://jsfiddle.net/tg5op333/27/